# Copy Module to JBoss with Cargo Maven Plugin

Tags: maven, jboss, cargo

I use the cargo maven plugin to donwload jboss as a dist and deploy our ear.
The JBoss we use is 7.1.0

My problem is, that we need an additional module in JBoss.
How can I copy a module to the JBoss in the target directory?

I tried it with this config:

```
<configuration>
    <type>standalone</type>
    <files>
        <file>
            <file>${project.basedir}/modules/springframework</file>
            <todir>../../installs/jboss-as-dist-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules</todir>
        </file>
    </files>
</configuration>
```

But this gives me this error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.1:start (start-container) on project gevomanagementservice_test_integration: Execution start-container of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.1:start failed: Failed to copy source file [C:\blabla/modules/springframework] to [C:\blabla\target\cargo\configurations\jboss71x/../../installs/jboss-as-dist-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/springframework]: C:\blabla\modules\springframework (The system cannot find the file specified) -> [Help 1]

It looks like I can only copy files with this config. Is there a possiblity to copy whole directories?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem as well. But I only need to copy a handful of files so that's not an issue for me. I haven't actually tried below solution myself but in theory it may work.

Assuming you want to deploy your artifact by cargo and run integration test. I think you may choose to bind your cargo:install goal to, say, package phrase. Then have another plugin, i.e. maven-antrun-plugin to do the folder copying task, in package phrase as well. Then in pre-integration-test phrase, you can bind cargo:start (or deploy. See [cargo reference](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin#Maven2plugin-gettingstarted)) to start your jboss instance. The maven life cycle will look like:

- clean
- package

  - cargo:install (installs JBoss)
  - antrun (copy files over to the installed JBoss)
- pre-integration-test

  - cargo:start (Note the document says this goal WON'T call cargo:install but reuse the same logic. I am not sure if this will erase your antrun effect. To be safe you may want to try cargo:deploy)
- integration-test
- post-integration-test

  - cargo:stop

Comment: The antrun solution is everytime the emergency solution, but I really don't like it. Then I rather zip the jboss with the modules and commit it into the repo.